# Modifying native prototypes node.js, where to place this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I want to do this project-wide for JavaScript arrays:

```
Array.prototype.getIndexBy = function (name, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i][name] == value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

How should I go about placing this code in my struture? would a module suffice? how would I correctly name a module that has this kind of behaviour?

I've thought on creating a `bootstrap.js` module with a method and then call it on my `server.js`, but I feel this is a code smell. It seems too dirty.

Comment: the entire notion smells. why modify the built-in types? use a utility function instead. [you don't even have to work for it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash)!

Comment: Yes I was scoping the code smell towards the structure. The bigger picture is much worse.

Comment: It has already been established that this is bad. Either way: *"where to place this code?"* Everywhere where `getIndexBy` is used. *"would a module suffice?"* Yes. *"how would I correctly name a module that has this kind of behaviour?"* There are no strict module naming conventions, but I would choose a name that indicates *to you* what it does.

Comment: Also, you should use `Object.defineProperty()` to define this method so you can set to to not be enumerable so it won't accidentally become part of a `for (x in array)` iteration (which is bad way to iterate arrays, but you might as well define your method in the safest way possible).